# unable to watch java local class instance in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, watch, local-class

Here is a small sample:

```
public class LocalClassSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Utils {
            public void printHello(String name) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + name);
            }
            public String outHello(String name) {
                return "hello " + name; 
            }
        }

        Utils util = new Utils();
        util.printHello("World");
    }
}
```

I put a break point at the last line. I am able to view util in the Variables window...

[image]

I try to view the same variable in the expressions window...it is unable to evaluate:

[image]
Update:

Even tried inspecting the variable in the Display View...it does not evaluate:
[image]

Comment: Try moving the `Utils` class outside of `main`?

Answer (score 0):

Expression eval a java expression like 'util.printHello("World")'
and return the result ("Hello World"). 'util' is not an 'expression' but just a variable name, if you want to inspect it, use the Variables view or the Inspect command.

Comment: Same issue there too...I cannot inspect...updated that issue in question

Comment: it seems like Eclipse does not have visibility of an inner class using the Inspect command. If you externalize Utils class, you should be able to inspect 'util' variable!